# How do I get my blog posts to appear on homepage?

Tags: homepage

My blog posts appear in the blog section, but not on the homepage. How can I make my blog posts appear on the homepage?

Comment: May you please elaborate your question? What have you tried? What do you have set up so far in your settings?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two different ways

01) Go to Settings > Reading and make the designation change and click “save changes”.
[image]

02) Go to Appearance > Customize > Static Front Page and choose to display the latest posts.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to modify the file: *front-page.php* in your child theme's folder and include this:

```
        <!-- loop through the posts -->
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?> <!-- post content -->

                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

            </article><!-- #post-## -->




        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

What the above snippet will do is go through every post on your site and include a very simple name, post type, and the actual post itself all within an  tag for each post.

You probably should place this snippet within the  with the ID "main", but you can put it anywhere you want -- on any page (not just the front)

Enjoy